# Bash script that lowercases files

Tags: performance, file-system, bash, perl

I have the following bash script that:

- Finds all files with `.cfc` and `.cfm` extension and converts them to lowercase
- Stores the relative file paths to those files (`filenames.txt`)
- Chops those files to get only the name, excluding the extension (`files.txt`)
- Loops through 1500 files checking for references to any of the other 1500 files and converts those to lower case

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# Search for references to JS function is all .cfm and .cfc functions
# Prompt to make sure
while true; do
    read -p "All .cfc and .cfm files in the theradoc/ directory and lower directories will be converted. Do you wish to contiue? (y/n)" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) make install; break;;
    [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
done
echo "Renaming files..."
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfm'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
echo "Indexing file names..."
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc' > filenames.txt
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfm' >> filenames.txt
echo "Editing file names..."
sed 's/theradoc.*\///g' filenames.txt > tmp.txt
sed 's/\.cf.*//g' tmp.txt > files.txt
rm tmp.txt
echo "Searching all files..."
a=($(wc filenames.txt))
lines=${a[0]}
count=0
while read fn; do
    echo "$fn | $count/$lines finished..."
    while read f; do
        perl -pi -e "s/$f/$f/gi" "$fn"
    done < files.txt
    count=$((count+1))
done < filenames.txt
```

**Runtime:** 4 hours

**Hardware:** MacBook 16GB RAM

I would definitely like to decrease the runtime of this as it may be needed to run on other systems with the same files.

Comment: It might be faster to construct one perl script instead of calling perl many times for each file.

Comment: I am willing to learn Perl if needed, as long as its not a complete, time consuming change. This project is winding down and I need to move on from it. Was just looking to improve this script before we ended.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my testing, constructing one Perl script and running it repeatedly is much faster (0.5s versus 3.6s) then running a new Perl instance for each replacement:

```
while read f; do
    echo "s/$f/$f/gi;" 
done < files.txt > s.pl

while read fn; do
    perl -pi s.pl "$fn"
    echo "$fn | $count/$lines finished..."
    count=$((count+1))
done < filenames.txt

rm s.pl
```

But it seems even faster (0.05s) to rewrite the whole thing to Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

my $dir = 'theradoc2';

my %change;

find(sub {
    return unless -f;
    undef $change{$_};
    rename $_, lc $_;
}, $dir);

my $regex = join '|',
            map quotemeta,
            sort { length $b <=> length $a }
            keys %change;
find(sub {
    return unless -f;
    my $file = $_;
    open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
    open my $OUT, '>', "$file.new" or die $!;
    while (<$IN>) {
        s/($regex)/\L$1/g;
        print {$OUT} $_;
    }
    close $OUT or die $!;
    unlink $file or die $!;
    rename "$file.new", $file or die $!;
}, $dir);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I used a little bit from many of the answers, but your loop for searching was the most helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This might not make a huge difference, but I'd start by combining your find calls.  It's been a while, but I think something like this will work (basically, match against *.cf followed by c or m):

```
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cf[cm]' > filenames.txt
```

Or

```
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cf?' > filenames.txt
```

You also don't seem to be using tmp.txt, so I'd tend to just pipe the output from the first sed call into the second:

```
sed 's/theradoc.*\///g' filenames.txt | sed 's/\.cf.*//g' > files.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

While the main problem of your script is obviously the `while read fn; do`
 loop (for which @choroba already provided a good solution I think) I want to point out a few problems which are often appearing in shell scripts:

```
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc'`;
```

It's generally a bad Idea to collect the output of `find` in a subshell like this, because that might be memory intensive. Also looping over the result by `for` is [discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

There is also no need to employ `tr` to lowercase variable contents, since bash has a built-in way to do this (but it's probably one of the lesser known features). I also don't see why you need to employ 4 `find` calls. So in total I think you can replace the whole block

```
echo "Renaming files..."
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfm'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
echo "Indexing file names..."
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc' > filenames.txt
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfm' >> filenames.txt
echo "Editing file names..."
sed 's/theradoc.*\///g' filenames.txt > tmp.txt
sed 's/\.cf.*//g' tmp.txt > files.txt
rm tmp.txt
```

with

```
echo "Renaming files..."
find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cf[cm]' | tee filenames.txt | while read f
do
    mv -v $f ${f,,}
done
echo "Editing file names..."
sed 's/theradoc.*\/\(.*\)\.cf/\1/' filenames.txt > files.txt
```

Of course this alone won't make a difference to your 4 hours runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that may help improve your code.

### Avoid the complication of using `make` if practical

Rather than invoking `make install`, I'd instead advocate something like this:

```
read -p "All .cfc and .cfm files in the $1 directory and lower directories will be converted.  Do you wish to continue?" affirm
case "$affirm" in 
    y|Y ) echo "yes";;
    n|N ) echo "no -- quitting program"; exit;;
    * ) echo "Invalid response -- quitting program"; exit;;
esac
```

The difference is that now the user doesn't need `make`.  Reducing dependencies results in a more portable script.

### Pass in the target directory as a parameter

Rather than hard code `theradoc`, it might be more convenient, especially for testing, to have the directory name as a command line argument.

### Use full path names for security

It's probably better to invoke `/usr/bin/sed` than just `sed` because the latter would be easy to substitute.  I could have a malicious `sed` on my path somewhere ahead of the real `sed` but it's generally harder to overwrite a system file.  Specifying a full path uses that to your (and your user's) advantage.

### Use `find` directly

Rather than creating multiple files and processing them, I think you will find that it's faster to simply use `find` directly rather than redirecting to a file and then processing that file line by line.

### Use `awk` for complex replacement

While `perl` can do regular expression matching and everything `awk` can do, you're currently invoking `perl` once per filename per file. That is, if there are 1500 files, you're invoking `perl` 1500 * 1500 times = 2,250,000 times.  It's already been suggested to just do the whole thing in `perl` which is certainly another option, although I find `perl` to be a "write only" language.  Once I write it, six months later I find that even I can't read and understand it.

### Construct just the replacement list

The only output file you really need is the one containing just the list of base file names.  That can be done like this:

```
find $1 -type f -iname '*.cf[cm]' -exec /usr/bin/basename {} ';' >basename.txt
```

Note that this uses `-exec` to run [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) to extract just the base part of the name (e.g. `/usr/bin/basename` would be converted to `basename`).

### Create a `bash` function to handle the replacement

I'd advocate exporting a function and then invoking `find` again like this:

```
export -f replaceAndRename
find $1 -type f -iname '*.cf[cm]' -exec bash -c 'replaceAndRename "$0"' {} \;
```

The `replaceAndRename` function might be implemented like this with `awk`:

```
replaceAndRename () {
    lcfile="$(echo $(/usr/bin/basename "$1") | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
    lcdir="$(/usr/bin/dirname "$1")"
    lcfile="${lcdir}/${lcfile}"
    /usr/bin/awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=tolower($1); next }{ 
        for (old in map) {
            gsub(old,map[old])
        }
        print
    }' basename.txt "$1" >"tmp.foo"
    retval="$?"
    if [ "$retval" -eq 0 ]; then
        rm "$1"
        mv tmp.foo "$lcfile"
    fi
}
```

This probably looks more complicated than it really is.  The first three lines simply create a version of the name that uses a lowercase base name.  Note, too that if there is something like a subdirectory with a name like `My Directory` we don't want to alter the directory name -- just the file name.

Next, we invoke `awk` and pass in the `basenames.txt` file created by the first invocation of `find` as well as the current file name to be processed, redirecting the output to a temporary file I've arbitrarily named `tmp.foo` but one could probably improve that by using [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) instead.

The `awk` script reads the first file in and creates an associative array of the original version of the filename mapped to the lowercase version.  Next, the second file is scanned and the map is used to make the appropriate substitutions. Finally the `print` within `awk` just prints the possibly modified line to the output which is redirected to `tmp.foo`.

Finally, if `awk` seemed to run successfully, we remove the original file and the move the `tmp.foo` into place using the lowercase version of the name.  We do it in this order in case one of the files is already in lowercase but may have had file references changed.

### Putting it all together

I don't have a convenient way to do benchmarking, but I believe this version of the script will improve your speed.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "All .cfc and .cfm files in the $1 directory and lower directories will be converted.  Do you wish to continue?" affirm
case "$affirm" in 
    y|Y ) echo "yes";;
    n|N ) echo "no -- quitting program"; exit;;
    * ) echo "Invalid response -- quitting program"; exit;;
esac
find $1 -type f -iname '*.cf[cm]' -exec /usr/bin/basename {} ';' >basename.txt
replaceAndRename () {
    lcfile="$(echo $(/usr/bin/basename "$1") | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
    lcdir="$(/usr/bin/dirname "$1")"
    lcfile="${lcdir}/${lcfile}"
    /usr/bin/awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=tolower($1); next }{ 
        for (old in map) {
            gsub(old,map[old])
        }
        print
    }' basename.txt "$1" >"tmp.foo"
    retval="$?"
    if [ "$retval" -eq 0 ]; then
        rm "$1"
        mv tmp.foo "$lcfile"
    fi
}
export -f replaceAndRename
find $1 -type f -iname '*.cf[cm]' -exec bash -c 'replaceAndRename "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: I would hope that most non-embedded *nix's have `make` installed.

Comment: You'd also have to hope that a corresponding `Makefile` exists and that the target `install` exists within that and does something useful.  I'd be much more inclined to minimize external dependencies to lessen the chances of something going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

At least as I understand it, you want to get the file names with relative paths. Right now,  you're invocation of `find` produces absolute paths, then you're using `sed` to remove the prefix you specified on the command line.

Assuming that's correct, you can tell `find` to produce just the part you want by specifying `-printf "%P\n"`.

For the part that remains (removing the file extensions) you can pipe the data directly from `find` to `sed`.

You also probably want to use `-depth` instead of `-d`, since the latter is deprecated.

Combining those, we end up with something like this:

```
find theradoc/ -depth -name *.cf[cm] -printf "%P\n" | sed s/\.cf.*//g > files.txt
```

I was going to suggest creating a sed script to handle the editing inside the index, but I see @choroba has already suggested roughly the same, so I'll leave that for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

There's no need to create extra processes, given that Bash can downcase variables:

```
mv -n -v "$f" "${,,f}"
```

Note also that I've double-quoted, as `$f` is not in our control, and I've given `mv` the "no-clobber" flag, as it doesn't look like you've considered what happens when different names case-fold to the same result.

---

```
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfc'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cfm'`;
    do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
```

The two `find` commands can be combined:

```
for f in `find theradoc/ -d -name '*.cf[cm]'`
    do mv -n -v "$f" "${f,,}"
done
```

The `,,` modifier is new in Bash 4, so not applicable to 3.x or earlier.

---

Your `find` command is run to completion before the first `mv` happens - you should pipe the output of `find` into a `read`/`while` loop.

Comment: Don't use brackets with `tr`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#tr_.5BA-Z.5D_.5Ba-z.5D

Comment: It should be noted that the lowercasing feature of `bash` is only as of `bash` version 4.0 so earlier versions will not work with this.  Also, the syntax is wrong.  It should be `${f,,}`